# Loading an image form a jar file in JRuby

Tags: jar, jruby

icon.png is inside myapp.jar

```
DANIELs-MacBook-Air-2:jrubyScreenshot dani [master] $ jar -tf myapp.jar | tail
....
icon.png
```

How can I load it?
This returns nil

```
f = java.lang.Object.new
image = java.awt.Toolkit::default_toolkit.get_image(f.java_class.resource("icon.png"))
```

Solution was:

```
 f = java.lang.Object.new
 url = f.java_class.resource("/icon.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe CLASSPATH

```
> jruby -J-classpath myapp.jar test.rb
```

---

```
include Java

f = java.lang.Object.new
url = f.java_class.resource("/icon.png")
image = java.awt.Toolkit::default_toolkit.get_image(url)
puts image
```

Comment: Not the classpath, but I just had to do "/icon.png". I still don't get why I have to say / but ti does work